# Сайт некорректно отображается в режиме desktop site в chrome

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Сделал адаптивный сайт, на мобильных устройствах и пк все выглядит нормально, но в режиме desktop site в chrome на мобильных устройствах шрифты меняют свои пропорции, гриды не адаптируются и т.д. Как можно сделать так, чтобы сайт в этом режиме соответствовал пк версии сайта?
Ссылка на сайт — https://startups-emilburganov.vercel.app/

[image: Непропорциональные шрифты и грид контейнер с блоками комментариев должны были выстроиться в колонку]

[image: Текст в зеленом блоке ни при каком размере экрана не должен переноситься (до 320px точно)]

1. Непропорциональные шрифты и грид контейнер с блоками комментариев должны были выстроиться в колонку
2. Текст в зеленом блоке ни при каком размере экрана не должен переноситься (до 320px точно)

Comment: у меня все нормально показывает, можете по точнее как они меняются фотографию предоставить?